# Associations Relationships in Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Ok, trying to learn rails commands on associations relationships in console

So if I have User that `has_many` posts, and Posts that `belongs_to` user ...

That means all this should work, correct? And these are *all* the the methods added automagically for this particular relationship, correct?

```
1. user.posts
2. user.posts=(posts)
3. user.posts << post
4. user.posts.delete(post)
5. user.posts.empty?
6. user.posts.size
7. user.post_ids
8. user.posts.clear
9. user.posts.find
10. user.posts.build(attributes={})
11. user.posts.create(attributes={})
```

`user` is: `user = User.create(:name => "Michael")`

result is: `#<User id: 3, name: "Michael", created_at: "2016-06-21 16:52:22", updated_at: "2016-06-21 16:52:22">`

&

`post` is: `post = Post.create(:body => "body of txt")`

result is: `#<Post id: 3, user_id: 3, body: "body of txt", created_at: "2016-06-21 16:53:51", updated_at: "2016-06-21 16:58:38">`

**1. For `user.posts`, I get this:**

`#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Post id: 3, user_id: 3, body: "body of txt", created_at: "2016-06-21 16:53:51", updated_at: "2016-06-21 16:58:38">, #<Post id: nil, user_id: 3, body: "txt of body2", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>`

**2. For `user.posts=(posts)`, I get this:**

`NameError: undefined local variable or method posts' for main:Object and a whole bunch more of rbenv stuff`

**3. For `user.posts << post`, I get this:**

`#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Post id: 3, user_id: 3, body: "body of txt", created_at: "2016-06-21 16:53:51", updated_at: "2016-06-21 16:58:38">, #<Post id: nil, user_id: 3, body: "txt of body2", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<Post id: 3, user_id: 3, body: "body of txt", created_at: "2016-06-21 16:53:51", updated_at: "2016-06-21 16:58:38">]>`

**5. For `user.posts.empty?`, I get this:**

`false`

**6. For `user.posts.size`, I get this:**

`3`

**7. For `user.post_ids`, I get this:**

`[3, nil, 3]`

**9. For `user.posts.find`, I get this:**

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Post without an ID`

**10. For `user.posts.build(attributes={:body => "random body of txt"})`, I get this:**

`#<Post id: nil, user_id: 3, body: "random body of txt", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Interesting thing about the one above is that when I do `Post.all`, that doesn't show up! But if I do `user.posts`, it does show up in that ...

**11. For `user.posts.create(attributes={})`, I get this:**

`=> #<Post id: 4, user_id: 3, body: "body of text via create method", created_at: "2016-06-21 17:49:50", updated_at: "2016-06-21 17:49:50">`

**4. For `user.posts.delete(post)`, I get this:**

`(0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  [["id", 3]]
   (1.8ms)  commit transaction
=> [#<Post id: 3, user_id: 3, body: "body of txt", created_at: "2016-06-21 16:53:51", updated_at: "2016-06-21 16:58:38">]`

**8. For `user.posts.clear`, I get this:**

`DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 3]]`

Which means now, when I run this: `user.posts`, I get this:

`#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

So, as you can see from above **#2** doesn't work ... as well **#9**. Why not?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT in response to answer (easier for clarification)**

ok, I did `posts = user.posts` which resulted:

`#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Post id: 5, user_id: 3, body: "body of txt", created_at: "2016-06-21 18:00:57", updated_at: "2016-06-21 18:01:11">, #<Post id: 6, user_id: 3, body: "body of txt2", created_at: "2016-06-21 18:22:02", updated_at: "2016-06-21 18:22:36">]>`

then I did `user.posts=(posts)` which resulted the same answer as above.

But when I ran `posts = Post.where(user: user)`, I got this:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.user: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user" = 3`

Also, when I ran `user.posts = posts`, I got this:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.user: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user" = 3`

In regards to `user.posts.find(Post.last.id)`, it worked if I did this:

`user.posts.find(Post.last)` but if I did something like this:

`user.posts.find(Post.last.6)`, I got this:

`SyntaxError: (irb):121: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dotuser.posts.find(Post.last.6)`

Answer (score 0):

For #2

You need to define what "posts" is.

If you are trying to "set" posts

```
posts = user.posts
```

If you want to do a comparison on the two you would do:

```
posts = Post.where(user: user)
user.posts == posts #should be true
```

For #9

You need to pass something into your find method:

```
user.posts.find(Post.last) #this returns an object if "user" created Post.last
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:

You can't do user.posts=(posts) because you set data with an array, hash, string, integer, etc.

An equals comparison operator should have 2 ='s. That was my mistake and I have corrected the post.

Comment: hey, thanks for responding. I responded in my post above.